# I am trying to figure out the XPath which will retrieve the img alt text from the following HTML

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath

I am trying to figure out the XPath which will retrieve the img alt text from the following HTML

```
<li class="m-navbar-item bottom-border float-left m-navbar-thumbnail">
    <img alt="Always There">
</li>
```

Comment: where is the HTML ?

Comment: Show your current code along with the exception/current output

Comment: <li class="m-navbar-item bottom-border float-left m-navbar-thumbnail">class="m-navbar-link uppercase float-left position-relative"
<figure class="fluid">
  <img alt="Always There" 
 </figure> <span class="fluid centered float-left"> $59.95</span>
       </a></li>

Comment: @user3538483 Can you check the HTML you have provided in the comments once? Update the question with the exact HTML please

Comment: @user3538483 , note that provided in comment HTML is broken. Update your question with **valid** HTML

Answer (score 1):

To get the alt text of a element, you need to use selenium web-driver API get attribute. You can locate the element using x-path. Your requirement may be as given below.

```
List<WebElement> lstItem = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//li[conatains(@class,'m-navbar-item')]/img");
for(WebElement item:lstItem){
    System.out.println(item.getAttribute("alt"));
}
```